# iis 7.5 failed request tracing not measuring speed

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I've set up Failed Request Tracing for a test site, but it is not measuring the speed the page takes to render.

It just says "Time Taken: 0 msec"

I've set up a similar test site on a different server and I do get a measurement for speed.

Failed Request Tracing should measure the speed the page takes to serve, right?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to benchmark the speed of a webpage, I recommend downloading [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

In regards to your problem seeing 0msec in FRT, you can try looking to see if you have the Output Caching module active. I have output caching enabled for images (.png) and saw a result of 0 msec just like your screenshot on subsequent runs.

> The first result (uncached): 16 msec
>
> The second test run (cached): 0 msec

The parameters for FRT I had enabled were: All Content (*), Status Code=200, Providers (all default).

ps. Try clearing your browser cache and do an `iisreset` from the command prompt and see if it updates.